# Random displays of members images

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

If I have an array of 50 spots, each spot contains 5 images, I want to randomly display each spot in a table format.  One spot per row (5 images) which will be 50 rows in total.  Using no database!

```
<?php
$allImages = array('Image1.jpg','Image2.jpg','Image3.jpg','Image4.jpg');
echo '<table>';
// loop for 12 rows
for($j=0; $j<12; $j++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    // loop to make 5 columns, 1 column for each image
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        echo '<td>';
        $img = $allImages[rand(0,3)];
        echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';
        echo '</td>';
    } echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: SO isnt going to do your homework for you. What have you tried?

Comment: $allImages = array('Image1.jpg','Image2.jpg','Image3.jpg','Image4.jpg');
  echo '<table>';
 // loop for 12 rows
  for($j=0; $j<12; $j++)
  {
   echo '<tr>';
  // loop to make 5 columns, 1 column for each image
  for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
  {
     echo '<td>';
     $img = $allImages[rand(0,3)];
     echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';
     echo '</td>';
  }
   echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';

Comment: lol I love how it is even worded exactly like a homework question. "Using no database!"

Comment: And his code being the code provided by another user from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528696/display-random-sets-of-items-from-a-list)...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

$allImages = array('Image1.jpg','Image2.jpg','Image3.jpg','Image4.jpg',
                   'Image2.jpg','Image3.jpg','Image4.jpg','Image2.jpg',
                   'Image3.jpg','Image4.jpg','Image2.jpg','Image3.jpg',
                   'Image4.jpg'); 
shuffle ( $allImages );
echo '<table><tr>'; 
for($j=0; $j<count($allImages); $j++) { 
  echo '<td>'; 
  echo '<img src="'.$allImages[$j].'">'; 
  echo '</td>'; 
  if(($j+1)%5==0) echo "</tr><tr>";
} 
echo '</tr></table>';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Markus, but remember each image that is listed in the array is actually 5 images.  Im trying to display groups or sets of 5 images so each array compartment has 5 images each spot meaning each set of 5 images is on one row.  Thanks again

Comment: Ok i understand, maybe you can use some parts for your solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<?php
$allImages = array(
        array ('Image01.jpg', 'Image02.jpg', 'Image03.jpg', 'Image04.jpg', 'Image05.jpg'),
        array ('Image11.jpg', 'Image12.jpg', 'Image13.jpg', 'Image14.jpg', 'Image15.jpg'),
        //.... So on upto 50 slots
        array ('Image501.jpg', 'Image502.jpg', 'Image503.jpg', 'Image504.jpg', 'Image505.jpg')
);

$spot_indexes = range(0,2,1); //in your case limit is 50
shuffle($spot_indexes);

foreach($spot_indexes as $index) {
    $spot_images = $allImages[$index];

    foreach($spot_images as $image) {
        echo '<img src ="' .$image. '" height="150px" width="100px" /> ' ;
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I had an error in this line $img = $allImages[$spot_indexes[$j][$i]];

Comment: @user2012105 fixed it now.

Comment: this is the answer:  <?php
$portfolios = array (
array( "001.jpg", "002.jpg", "003.jpg","004.jpg","005.jpg"),
 array( "006.jpg", "007.jpg", "008.jpg","009.jpg","010.jpg"),
 array( "011.jpg", "012.jpg", "013.jpg","014.jpg","015.jpg"),
);

 shuffle($portfolios);
foreach( $portfolios  as $leo) {
foreach( $leo as $i) {  echo  '<img src ="' .$i. '" height="150px" width="100px" /> ' ;
}
echo "<br>";

}

?>

Comment: @user2012105 Did it randomise the image display?

Comment: @user2012105 [How to ask Questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) please read it completely.